# chromeのデベロッパーツールのスマホモードで複数指のタッチをするには、どういうキーの操作をすれば良いですか？

Tags: google-chrome

chromeのデベロッパーツールで複数指のタッチをするには、どういうキーの操作をすれば良いですか？

Answer (score 2):

ピンチ操作であればShiftキーを押しながらマウスをドラッグしてみて下さい。

**追記**
以下のリンク先にDevToolsのショートカット一覧がありますが、パン操作については記載が無いのでエミュレーション出来ないのかもしれません。
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts

Comment: ありがとうございます！複数指Pan（スクロール）はできないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！となると、実機で試すしかないかもしれないですね。